# Extending ASP.NET MVC Register

Tags: asp.net-mvc, passwords, ravendb

I have RavenDB set-up as my choice of DB in my MVC project. Currently the **Register** process is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }
```

I have a method in my Database logic class that will be used to store user objects such as the `User`:

```
    public void SaveEntity(ModelBase entity)
    {
        using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(entity);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

`ModelBase` is the base object for everything that can be saved to the database and the User class which contains properties such as Username, Password, Email etc will also be one of the objects that will be saved.

Would my `SaveEntity` method be sufficient? And how would I need to change the `Register` in order to use my SaveEntity` method to store the user. I would also like to apply encryption of some sort to store the password.

Answer (score 0):

With RavenDB, everything can be saved to the database, there's no real use for that ModelBase thing, which looks like a remnant from the 3-tier architecture days.

You may want to read this: http://novuscraft.com/blog/ravendb-and-the-repository-pattern

And also this, about how to use RavenDB in MVC websites - there's a much easier way to achieve the SaveEntity functionality you are looking for: http://ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website